# Synchronization for several goroutines using channels

Tags: go, concurrency, synchronization, channel, goroutine

I need to start a number of workers with single task queue and single result queue. Each worker should be started in different goroutine. And I need to wait till all workers will be finished and task queue will be empty before exiting from program.
I have prepare small example for goroutine synchronization.
The main idea was that we count tasks in queue and waiting for all workers to finish jobs. But current implementation sometime miss values.
Why this happends and how to solve the problem?
The sample code:

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "strconv"
)

const num_workers = 5

type workerChannel chan uint64

// Make channel for tasks
var workCh workerChannel
// Make channel for task counter
var cntChannel chan int

// Task counter
var tskCnt int64

// Worker function
func InitWorker(input workerChannel, result chan string, num int) {
    for {
        select {
        case inp := <-input:
            getTask()
            result <- ("Worker " + strconv.Itoa(num) + ":" + strconv.FormatUint(inp, 10))
        }
    }
}

// Function to manage task counter
// should be in uniq goroutine
func taskCounter(inp chan int) {
    for {
        val := <-inp
        tskCnt += int64(val)
    }
}

// Put pask to the queue
func putTask(val uint64) {
    func() {
        fmt.Println("Put ", val)
        cntChannel <- int(1)
        workCh <- val
    }()
}

// Get task from queue
func getTask() {
    func() {
        cntChannel <- int(-1)
    }()
}

func main() {
// Init service channels
    abort := make(chan os.Signal)
    done := make(chan bool)

// init queue for results
    result := make(chan string)

// init task queue
    workCh = make(workerChannel)

// start some workers
    for i := uint(0); i < num_workers; i++ {
        go InitWorker(workCh, result, int(i))
    }

// init counter for synchro
    cntChannel = make(chan int)
    go taskCounter(cntChannel)

// goroutine that put some tasks into queue
    go func() {
        for i := uint(0); i < 21; i++ {
            putTask(uint64(i))
        }

        // wait for processing all tasks and close application
        for len(cntChannel) != 0 {}
        for tskCnt != 0 {}
        for len(workCh) != 0 {}
        for len(result) != 0 {}

        // send signal for close
        done <- true
    }()

    signal.Notify(abort, os.Interrupt)
    for {
        select {
        case <-abort:
            fmt.Println("Aborted.")
            os.Exit(0)

        // print results
        case res := <-result:
            fmt.Println(res)

        case <-done:
            fmt.Println("Done")
            os.Exit(0)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [sync.WaitGroup](http://godoc.org/sync#WaitGroup) to wait for goroutines to complete.  Close channels to cause loops reading on channels to exit.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type workerChannel chan uint64

const num_workers = 5

func main() {

    results := make(chan string)
    workCh := make(workerChannel)

    // Start workers
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(num_workers)
    for i := 0; i < num_workers; i++ {
        go func(num int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            // Loop processing work until workCh is closed
            for w := range workCh {
                results <- fmt.Sprintf("worker %d, task %d", num, w)
            }

        }(i)
    }

    // Close result channel when workers are done
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(results)
    }()

    // Send work to be done
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 21; i++ {
            workCh <- uint64(i)
        }
        // Closing the channel causes workers to break out of loop
        close(workCh)
    }()

    // Process results. Loop exits when result channel is closed.
    for r := range results {
        fmt.Println(r)
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/ZifpzsP6fNv

Comment: It works! But for this case tasks will wait till one of the worker will be freed. I want to implement case when goroutine for generating tasks will be able to put as much items to the queue, as we have available memory. And all of them will be proceeded one-by-one with workers. Is it possible? One of use cases is described in my prev. comment

Comment: Is it sufficient to increase the size of the workCh channel? If not, then use [sync.Cond](https://godoc.org/sync#Cond) to implement a queue with no size limit.

Comment: @CeriseLimón, would it make a difference if you would use a buffered channel? e.g. `results := make(chan string, num_workers)` I modified your example here: https://play.golang.org/p/6Jpjs887Wbc, it seems that the results are ordered, but I don't understand why.

Comment: @StevenFerrer The results are ordered due to details of the implementation. It valid for your program to print results in other orders.

Comment: @CeriseLimón, thank you for your quick response. You're right, I tried it with my code and the results are not ordered. I was hoping that there is a way to truly make the results to come in order. Something like a queue but still maintaining async processing of the jobs.

Comment: @CeriseLimón, Good idea! Here's the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56916688/golang-ordering-results-of-goroutines

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using close(chan) for this kind of tasks.

WaitGroup version.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "sync"
)

func worker(in chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for i := range in {
        log.Println(i)
    }

}

func main() {
    in := make(chan int)
    lc := 25
    maxValue := 30
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(lc)
    for i := 0; i < lc; i++ {
        go worker(in, &wg)
    }

    for c := 0; c <= maxValue; c++ {
        in <- c
    }
    close(in)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Channel version

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
)

func worker(in chan int, end chan struct{}) {
    defer func() { end <- struct{}{} }()
    for i := range in {
        log.Println(i)
    }

}

func main() {
    in := make(chan int)
    lc := 25
    maxValue := 30
    end := make(chan struct{})
    var fin int
    go func() {
        for {
            <-end
            fin++
            log.Println(`fin`, fin)
            if fin == lc {
                break
            }
        }
        close(end)
        os.Exit(0)
    }()
    for i := 0; i < lc; i++ {
        go worker(in, end)
    }

    for c := 0; c <= maxValue; c++ {
        in <- c
    }
    close(in)
    <-make(chan struct{})
}
```

Comment: In both versions you offer to close channel from the inside of the worker. This is not the case for me. In my case queue will be updated in runtime and I have no idea where is the end of data. Lets say that remote host enumerate files and provide filenames to the queue. The worker is calculating hash from the filename (the process took up to 30 seconds). I want to start a number of workers and goroutine that will receive filename and put them to the queue. Each worker is much slower than collector.  At the end of files, special command will be received an we must wait for finish the queue.

Comment: 1. I close the channel from main, not from the worker. Its a good role of thumb to close the resource in the same function/object that created it.
2. Closing the channel close it only for writing, all the buffered messages will continue to be processed.
3. I didn't understand the case. Its an HTTP server? A daemon that read from pub/sub queue? or a job?